# Drawer is not functional in first render from Server Side Render

Tags: reactjs, meteor, material-ui, server-side-rendering

I need to implement SSR in my Meteor app, where I am having issues with [Drawer](https://material-ui.com/demos/drawers) from [MaterialUI](https://material-ui.com/) to toggle with onClick event handler.

Any boilerplate or example links would be helpful.

**Versions**:

@material-ui/core:3.1.1

@material-ui/icons:3.0.1

METEOR@1.8-rc.16

This is how I have currently added Drawer:

```
  const Header = props => {
  const { classes, handleDrawerToggle, mobileOpen } = props

  return (
    <div>
      <StyledAppBar>
        <TopBorders>
          <div />
          <div />
          <div />
          <div />
        </TopBorders>
        <Grid container justify="center">
          <Grid item lg={9} md={10} sm={9} xs={12}>
            <Toolbar>
              <div style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                <Link to="/">
                  <LogoImage src="/img/Logo.png" alt="Drone Pilot" />
                </Link>
              </div>
              <div>
                <Hidden mdUp implementation="css">
                  <IconButton
                    aria-label="open drawer"
                    onClick={() => handleDrawerToggle(!mobileOpen)}
                  >
                    <MenuIcon />
                  </IconButton>
                </Hidden>
                <Hidden smDown implementation="css">
                  <NavItem />
                </Hidden>
              </div>
            </Toolbar>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </StyledAppBar>
      <Drawer
        variant="temporary"
        anchor="right"
        open={mobileOpen}
        onClose={() => handleDrawerToggle()}
        ModalProps={{
          keepMounted: true, // Better open performance on mobile.
        }}
        classes={{
          paper: classes.drawerPaper,
        }}
      >
        <NavItem />
      </Drawer>
    </div>
  )
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  mobileOpen: state.mainReducer.mobileOpen,
})

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators(ActionCreators, dispatch)
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(withStyles(styles)(Header))
```

Answer (score 1):

Drawer's functionality is managed by state toggling, which is fired up by event handlers. And they are not pushed in with SSR rendered content. So, this is how react suppose to work. And events are attached when client side kicks in.

ref:

> If you call ReactDOM.hydrate() on a node that already has this server-rendered markup, React will preserve it and only attach event handlers, allowing you to have a very performant first-load experience.

[React Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html)